# how can i solve this error in schemaspy

Tags: java, schemaspy

```
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

ERROR - mssql08 (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: mssql08 (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running a version without support for mssql08.
Verify by

```
java -jar schemaspy.jar -dbhelp
```

You can get the latest snapshot at

https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/blob/master/README.md#latest-build